# Return error level Batch

Tags: batch-file, registry, errorlevel

I have this script and the script works fine. Except one part. I am trying to return the error level after each query I do to determine my error level. I know I have syntax that is wrong please help.

```
@echo off
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "ports=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Ports"

rem get only the first token of each line of "reg query"
for /f %%I in (
    'reg query "%ports%"'
) do (
IF !errorlevel!==0  echo(%%I | findstr /i "c:\\convertdoc\\output\\silentprinttemp\\.*\.ps" >NUL && (
        rem (if "findstr" didn't exit with an abnormal error code)
        echo Deleting item %%I
        ECHO [PW-MOD] reg delete "%ports%" /v "%%I" /f
    )
)
```

[edited by `Dk 68 61 63 6b` in response to comments]
[re-edited PW to join broken line and disable potentially damaging instruction `'reg delete'`]

Comment: if you `ECHO !errorlevel!` as the first instruction in your `DO` block, you'll find it's set to `1`, therefore the remainder of the block won't be executed - or is there some other `error` - perhaps the error that the `IF` statement must be on the same physical line as the instruction to be performed on `true`. Also not good form to post anything that will potentially delete (files or in this case registry entries) - `ECHO` them instead...

Comment: I am trying to delete registry entries. I am trying to get a error if anything but that string is found not true

Comment: How do i keep reg delete still working?

Comment: The issue is that your code could have deleted entries on other people's machines. The easy way is to simply `ECHO` the command you want to execute. When you are sure that the command is correct, you simply remove the `ECHO` and the command is activated - for you, on YOUR machine. On my testing of your code, I found that `'reg query "%ports%"'` always returned errorlevel 1. That is the reason that your test `IF !errorlevel!==0` is not executing the `ECHO(%%I...` - and the `echo deleting...` and `reg delete` will only occur if the `ECHO(%%I...` is executed AND the string found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up delayed expansion in `help set`. It explains your issue exactly.

To solve it use

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

and then `!errorlevel!` instead of `%errorlevel%`.

Another option would be to use

```
if not errorlevel 1
```

(with slightly different semantics that are likely not relevant in your case).